# Postgres query on very large table with indexes still very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

The following query is running very slowly despite mytable being indexed on `recdate` (mytable has > 60 M records) query takes almost 7 minutes.

```
select to_char(recdate, 'yyyy'), count(*)
from mytable
group by to_char(recdate, 'yyyy')
```

Comment: 7 minutes for full table scan is not so long. Anyway do you have index on recdate?

Comment: all questions about performance require execution plan...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: But a query that simply read all rows from a table will probably not benefit much from indexing. What is your exact Postgres version (`select version()` will tell you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide execution plan, but I guess function-based index would cover

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx ON mytable( to_char(recdate,'yyyy'));
```

query:

```
select to_char(recdate,'yyyy'),count(*) 
from mytable 
group by to_char(recdate,'yyyy')
```

Comment: I was beginning to think that but seems overkill if this is only a casual one off query.

Comment: I'm not sure if that index helps at all. I believe it will only help if a better estimate for the number of groups leads to a better plan; the index itself will not be used for the query.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: What makes you say so? The index is on the grouped-by expression, so it seems perfect for the task.

Comment: @Tony Wolff: You should accept this answer nonetheless. This is the index needed to speed up the query as requested. If you decide not to speed up the query, this is still the correct answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are right in this case, but only if an *Index Only Scan* can be used, right?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: The index contains all references per year and the query wants to count references per year, so of course this will be an index-only scan. There is no additional information from the table needed.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner What about the information if a tuple is visible or not?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: tuple? visible? You've lost me there.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html): But there is an additional requirement for any table scan in PostgreSQL: it must verify that each retrieved row be “visible” to the query's MVCC snapshot, as discussed in [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/mvcc.html).

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: I didn't know of this. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyWolff . . . Does this improve performance?  If so, how much?